# Exists fail into stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exists

This code work:

```
declare @IDArticulo int = 12
declare @DescripcionArticuloVEL varchar(150) = (select top 1 DescripcionArticulo 
from TabVentasEnLineaDetalle where IDArticulo=@IDArticulo and exists (select DescripcionArticulo 
from TabVentasEnLineaDetalle where IDArticulo=@IDArticulo))
print @DescripcionArticuloVEL
```

but, into stored procedure return this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SPMaestroArticulos, Line 43 
>       You can only specify an expression in the selection list when the subquery is not specified with EXISTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single `SELECT` statement. The inner `SELECT` statement is unnecessary. I would re-write your query as:

```
SELECT TOP (1) @DescripcionArticuloVEL = DescripcionArticulo 
FROM TabVentasEnLineaDetalle 
WHERE IDArticulo = @IDArticulo;
```